# Prime number generator in C++ ( alex allain jumping into c++)

Tags: c++, c++11, numbers, primes

i just started learning C++ , I am an art major (i know) and i started learning c++ from Alex Allain's jumping into c++ and in that book i have understood most of the stuff , I am currently stuck on prime number generator and i am having difficulty in the grasping the algothrim.I am not able to understand it after the first for loop

```
#include <iostream>
// note the use of function prototypes
bool isDivisible (int number, int divisor);
bool isPrime (int number);

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        if (isPrime(i)) {
            cout << i << endl;
        }
    }
}

bool isPrime(int number)// i don't understand from this point onward.
{
    for (int i = 2; i < number; i++) {
        if (isDivisible(number, i)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

bool isDivisible(int number, int divisor)
{
    return number % divisor == 0;
}
```

I humbly request anyone to help me understand this code step by step.
thank you so much

Comment: Please don't post code as image. What is your question? What do you not understand? How would you check with pen and paper if a number is prime?

Comment: don't post a link to an image of the code, post the code here

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please[edit] your question to include any code (or, really, *any* text) as text. Code in the form of a [mcve].

Comment: Hi there, could you type in the code so that people don't need to click on an image to see what you're talking about.

Comment: I also recommend that you learn some common *debugging* techniques, like [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), or using an actual debugger to step through the program statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: Prime number is only divisible by one and by itself. This is a naive implementation, that checks the opposite condition - if there is any other divisor than `1` and `n`, the number is *not prime*. This is the simplest solution possible, but it's also the slowest.

Comment: i have posted the code as many requested, sorry for inconvenience ,

Comment: Any explanation of the algorithm won't make sense to you, unless you know what a prime number is.   Do you?

Comment: @Peter I know a number is a prime number if its only divisible by 1 or itself.

Comment: @JohnFilleau i have added code

Comment: @Michelle added code now

Comment: @Eric added code now

Comment: @ThomasSablik added code now

Comment: @Cansh Just read the **_Simple Methods_** section of [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test) or [read this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/primality-test-set-1-introduction-and-school-method/). In your code, they are checking all numbers from `0` to `100`. If prime, they print the number. `x % y == 0` checks if `x` gives `0` as remainder on dividing with `y`, i.e. if `x` is divisible by `y`.

Comment: Another key point is how numbers increment. Have a look at what ++ does in the code.

Comment: @Cansh thanks for posting the text. What parts of the code don't you understand? You can add comments to the code you posted on each part you don't get. If there's a line you don't get, please explain any parts of it you DO understand so we can focus on what you don't get. Otherwise I could assume you don't know C++ at all, and I'm not interested in teaching you C++ from scratch. I also formatted your code for you so it was easier for us to read. Pretend you're asking your question to a busy colleague. Make it as easy as us as possible to focus on the problem.

Comment: It's also possible that you understand the code, but don't understand the algorithm. Are you having trouble understanding the syntax of code? Or are you having trouble understanding the algorithm? It could be both.

Comment: You added the code but you didn't answer my question, e.g. how would you check if `289` is a prime number with pen and paper?

Comment: @ThomasSablik i don't really know but my guess is to try to divide it with numbers upto 288.?

Comment: What does `isPrime` do?

Comment: @ThomasSablik got it :). i actually got it thanks man

Answer (score 1):

To understand the above code you first need to understand what are prime numbers.
**A prime number is a number that is only divisible by 1 and itself.**

For example:-

```
          5 is divisible by 1 and 5 only (prime)

          4 is divisible by 1, 2 and 4 (not prime)
```

So to check whether the number is prime or not we need to check whether it is divisible by any other number other than 1 and itself and if it is divisible by any other number then it is not prime.

So now let's understand this using the above code :-

```
bool isPrime(int number) {
   for(int i=2;i<number;i++) { // this loops runs from 2 to number - 1
     if(isDivisible(number,i)) { // this checks if the number is divisible by i if the number is divisible by i then the function isDivisible will return true
        return false; // If the above condition is true that means the number is divisible by i and that means the number is not prime so we return false
     }
   }
   return true; // and if the number is not divisible by any number between (2 to number-1) that means it is prime so we return true
}
```

for the second part of the code, we check whether the number is divisible by i

```
bool isDivisible(int number ,int divisor) {
    return number % divisor == 0; /* it return true if number is divisible by divisor and false otherwise.
    example:-
      1. number = 4 divisor = 2
      4%2 == 0 true
      2. number = 5 divisor = 3
      5%3 == 0 false
    */
}
```

So now let's see the whole code in working.

example:-

1. number = 5

   isPrime(5)

   we loop from 2 to 4

   isDivisible(5,2)  = false;

   isDivisible(5,3) = false;

   isDivisible(5,4) = false;

   loop ends and we return true (the number is prime);
2. number  = 4

   isPrime(4)

   we loop from 2 to 3

   isDivisible(4,2) = true;

   the above condition is true so we return false (the number is not prime);

Hope this helped you in understanding the above code